# Logic About GetTurn Back_End Web Api Project C#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

Hello Every One m i have a question about Web Api Asp.net core
I recently became an intern of a company that gave me a database that I had to create relationships with this database and I did it.
Now I am working on a project which is of the web ip type and I have already created a Jason web token so that every time a user needs to log in, he will send a token to him, but now we are talking about whether users want to access the sections I have already defined several roles in the database, which include: doctor, secretary, manager, admin, superadmin, and now I want to create a controller for the menu section, where a series of these people, for example, doctors only They can see some of the buttons and sections of the site's menu, and some others, such as the secretary, cannot see the different parts of the doctors.
Now I am confused what to do.
i have this Table on my Model's Folder : 1_User , 2_UserRole , 3 _Role , 4_RolePermission ,5_Permission
Thank you if someone can help me

First, in this work, I made a login and register controller that controls whether the user has already registered or not and also checks whether the input format is correct.
What should I do for the next controls?
I have several sections for it, including center, clinic, tariff, calendar, etc
I know I should create a controller for them, but I don't know exactly what I should do for them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you log in successfully, you can query the current user's role information, and then add it to the JWT Token (using claims) to determine the current login role information. After producing the complete token, you can return it to the client (if necessary To store Token or related information on the server side, you may need to use distributed cache such as session). In this case, your application generates a token when the user logs in and sends it to the user. The user then sends this token back to the server on every request. The server validates this token to confirm the user's identity.

To the menu buttons, if you want to dynamically generate it on the server side, you can use the role in the `[Authorize]` attribute in your controller or method to specify the accessible user roles. In this way, different controllers or methods can be accessed through different roles to return specific menus.
For details, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

If you want to display specific menu items at the client level, in the layout page or menu page, you can use something like `User.IsInRole("Doctor")` in the front-end code to determine the user's role information to decide whether to display specific menu item options.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Doctor"))
{
     <button>Doctor</button>
}
```

Or you can check the user claims and according to it to display menu buttons:

```
@if(User.HasClaim("Role", "Doctor"))
{
     <button>Doctor</button>
}
```

Which method to use specifically depends on your project needs. You can use the above methods as a reference.